# Is there a way to filter out the elements of a List containing object having a String element based on another List of String

Tags: java, string, list

I have a List of an object `List<Object>` which Objects contains String elements . Now There is also another List of String `List<String>` .

I want the first List to only contain objects which are elements of the second list.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: You should have a `Set` instead of a `List` for whatever you want to look up.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett I am doing it by iterating though the lists which i think is the most trivial solution .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `contains()` method of the list and that's convenient in your case since it will `equals()` check the Strings.

e.g.

```
  List<String> otherList = new ArrayList<>();
  List<Object> test = new ArrayList<>();
  Iterator<Object> it = test.iterator();
  while(it.hasNext()){
       if(!otherList.contains(it.next().getString())) it.remove();
   }
```

or in Java8 streams

```
 test.stream().filter(e -> otherList.contains(e.getString()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will generate you a new `List`.